# How to upload the folder to vm instance from bucket storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have annotated dataset. I am trying to use this dataset at Linux virtual machine in google cloud. Please help with steps

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) installed in your VM (which you can easily install following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)), you can easily download the files to your VM using the following command:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://<YOUR-BUCKET-NAME>/<YOUR-FOLDER-PATH>/*   <DESTINATION-DIRECTORY>
```

This would be the most straight-forward answer, however, if you need to automate this, you could use the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to do this process using code.